# Reordering of table to get min changes

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe containing the results of an optimization problem

```
                       u1    u2    u3   value
time                                                
2021-06-28 00:00:00    ON    ON    ON   1.000
2021-06-28 01:00:00    ON    ON    ON   1.000
2021-06-28 02:00:00    ON    ON    ON   1.000
2021-06-28 03:00:00    ON    ON    ON   1.000
2021-06-28 04:00:00   OFF    ON    ON   0.336
2021-06-28 04:00:00    ON    ON    ON   0.664
2021-06-28 05:00:00   OFF    ON    ON   0.410
2021-06-28 05:00:00    ON    ON    ON   0.590
2021-06-28 06:00:00   OFF    ON    ON   1.000
```

In some hours only one combination of u1,u2,u3 is ON
In others, the time step is split between two or more combinations
I want to reorder the results such that the changes of 'ON' / 'OFF' will be minimal
**Changes can be done only within the same time step**
For example, the desired result for the above table will be:
(One switch in the 04:00 rows)

```
                       u1    u2    u3     value
time                                                
2021-06-28 00:00:00    ON    ON    ON     1.000
2021-06-28 01:00:00    ON    ON    ON     1.000
2021-06-28 02:00:00    ON    ON    ON     1.000
2021-06-28 03:00:00    ON    ON    ON     1.000
2021-06-28 04:00:00    ON    ON    ON     0.664
2021-06-28 04:00:00   OFF    ON    ON     0.336
2021-06-28 05:00:00   OFF    ON    ON     0.410
2021-06-28 05:00:00    ON    ON    ON     0.590
2021-06-28 06:00:00   OFF    ON    ON     1.000
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Why wouldn't switching the 05:00 rows also be a valid solution?

Comment: Switching the 05:00 rows is also a valid solution.
There is more than a single solution